# Windows 10 linux subsystem ubuntu trying to install python pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, package, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It's the first time ever for me to use a linux terminal. In my case I activated windows 10 linux subsystem and installed ubuntu because as I have seen it's much more versatile than windows cmd. Now I was trying to create venv for my python project through ubuntu terminal, but i can't undersand why every time i run a command that requires the previous installation of a package such as `pip install ...` or `virtualenv -p python3 venv` (which i had already installed time ago through windows cmd) I get 
`Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install virtualenv`

and if I run the suggested commands I get:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualenv`

In all this my current working directory is the project directory where i intend to place my files, everything worked when i tried to achieve the same result with windows cmd.
Hope what i wrote is clear enough.

Comment: I think you forgot to uptate apt before trying to install your package ? Execute `sudo apt update` then retry your command. It should work.

Comment: Yes, it was that easy, thanks a lot!

Comment: i think i might have some problems understanding the nature of this ubuntu terminal from the windows subsystem. Every time i need to use an external package such as selenium or others that i had installed earlier through the windows cmd i need to install them again through the ubuntu terminal. I will do more research.